# SQL query to find out of order records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sequence

I have a PHP program w/MySQL database which contains many records.  Two columns of particular relevance are incidentnumber and date.  These both move forward only.  However, sometimes a user enters data which is out of sequence; eg:

```
Incident Date
1        Jan 1 2000
2        Jan 1 2010
3        Jan 1 2002
```

It appears that incident 2 was entered with the wrong date, it should be Jan 1 2001.

Is there any way to query for records where the date is out of sequence?  Or do I have to iterate through all records tracking last date to find the error?

ADDED NOTE: The incidents are not sequential (they might go 1,3,6,123, etc).  Nor are the dates sequential.  And these are columns in the same table.

Comment: does mysql have window functions?

Comment: are the incidentnumbers ALWAYS in regular incremental sequence (incremented by one) or can there be iregularities?

Comment: @wildplasser: no. MySQL's SQL capabilities are stuck in the late 90s ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : as you probably have concluded too, creating two "parallel" rank() (or row_number()) is the obvious solution: `where rnk1 <> rnk2` would do the rest. (BTW: there is a nice EWD anecdote about an exam, where the candidate (who had been exposed to FORTRAN) did not see a solution based on double indexing `x = a[a[y]];` or such :-) BTW: I could do the ranking with a CTE, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command selects any records for which there exists in the same table a record with a lower Incident number but a higher Date.

```
 SELECT * FROM TableName T1 WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM TableName T2 
      WHERE T2.Incident < T1.Incident AND T2.Date > T1.Date)
```

This slightly more complex command will find only records for which are out of order in "both directions", meaning they have an later dated record earlier in the file and an earlier dated record later in the file.  This avoids the situation in which making a mistake in a very early record in the file will make all the subsequent records appear out of order.  However, it will not catch a problem in the two records with the lowest or highest incident numbers.

```
 SELECT * FROM TableName T1 WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM TableName T2 
      WHERE T2.Incident < T1.Incident AND T2.Date > T1.Date)
 AND EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM TableName T2 
      WHERE T2.Incident > T1.Incident AND T2.Date < T1.Date)
```

Finally, as ruakh points out in the comments, the above query gives you ALL the out-of-order records.  Although that is, technically, what you wanted it makes it difficult to find the "point of breakage" in the chain of dates.  The following query will give you only the records where the chain gets messed up, does not require IncidentID to increase monotonically, and allows deletions of incidents.

```
 SELECT * FROM TableName T1 WHERE 
    Date < (SELECT Date FROM TableName T2 WHERE T2.IncidentID = 
   (SELECT MAX(IncidentID) FROM TableName T3 WHERE T3.IncidentID < T1.IncidentID))
 OR Date > (SELECT Date FROM TableName T2 WHERE T2.IncidentID = 
   (SELECT MAX(IncidentID) FROM TableName T3 WHERE T3.IncidentID > T1.IncidentID))
```

(Not tested, since I don't have a copy of MySQL handy).

Comment: That could potentially give a large number of records, though. For example, if the last two records are (mistakenly) in 1900, then that query will give every single correctly-dated record.

Comment: In that case, it would only give the last two records (all other records do NOT have a lower incident number with a higher date).  However, in the reverse case (a low Incident number with a very late date) will produce the situation you describe.

Comment: You're right, I had that backward. Regardless, the problem is there; so I don't think this is a good way to find the out-of-order records.

Comment: That, in large part, depends on your definition of "out of order".  If the first record is after all the other records in the file, all the other records are, technically, out of order.  Presumably, the intent is that this command should never return any records, if it does, someone would investigate and correct the errors.  However, see my edit.

Comment: Re: "Presumably, the intent is that this command should never return any records, if it does, someone would investigate and correct the errors": Ah. I was assuming that the intent was that this command should never return any records (as you say), and that when it does return records, it contains the necessary information for the error to be seen and fixed (rather than requiring another "someone would investigate" step).

Comment: I don't see how an "automatic fix" could be applied when the only information possible to derive from the database is that there is an inconsistency between two records in the database.  There's no way to know which is correct.  In the OP's example you can only tell that one of the three records is out of order, not which one.

Comment: O.K., that's true; but even a query that returns just the two records with adjacent increasing `Incident` and decreasing `Date` gives actual information that's useful in an investigation -- it shows you where to look -- which is infinitely better than a query whose output is a Boolean, "yes problem" or "no problem", with "yes problem" being represented by (potentially) large numbers of records. Because if the result of "yes problem" is "O.K., now I need to write a query to *find* the problem", then that indicates a deficiency in the original query.

Comment: Oi.  I've added a query to my response that will return only records on either side of a breakage in the chain of increasing dates across increasing incident numbers.  It handles skipped incident numbers (the OP says they only increase, but not necessarily monotonically).  In the case you're concerned about, it will only return the records you want to see, although it will have to be run repeatedly because it may not return all the records that need to be updated to fix the problem.  Also, while it returns fewer records in some cases in the actual sample it will return more records.

Comment: +1, very nice. :-) This is definitely the best answer now, it's too bad I can't give you more than +1 . . .

Comment: wow...I have to try to understand that (it might take a few days).  I'm not sure if it was clear, but the data are columns in the SAME table.  So does your solution assume T1 and T2 are different tables?

Comment: No, Michelle, the only table used is the one you described in your post (You didn't state the name, so I just wrote "TableName" instead).    The query looks at each record in the table and then looks in the SAME table twice more -- once to learn the number of the immediately prior incident ID, and once to learn what date is associated with that ID.  Then, it repeats that logic for the immediately following incident ID.  T1, T2, and T3 are aliases used to allow you to specify these three uses of the same table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable t1
     inner join yourtable t2
     on t1.incident=t2.incident-1
     and t1.date>t2.date
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have misread the query. Mea culpa. I'll delete my earlier comment. So, +1; but note that this will miss the case where (for example) incident #3 comes after incident #5, and incident #4 has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This selects all of the ids where the date is greater than the next records date. That should tell you which ones are out of order.

```
SELECT Incident FROM table a 
    WHERE a.Date > (SELECT b.Date FROM table b WHERE b.Incident = (a.Incident + 1))
```

Comment: +1, but note that this will miss the case where (for example) incident #3 comes after incident #5, and incident #4 has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In case that the IncidentID column is always in a regular incremental sequence:

```
SELECT c.IncidentID AS cincID, p.IncidentID AS pincID, 
c.Date AS cDate, p.Date AS pDate,
DATEDIFF(c.Date, p.Date)
FROM Incident c, Incident p
WHERE c.IncidentID = (p.IncidentID + 1)
AND datediff(c.Date, p.Date) < 1
```